# When I try to run google assistant on my raspberry pi i get this error

Tags: python, linux, google-assistant-sdk, google-assist-api

I followed the tutorial from google. https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/prototype/getting-started-pi-python/run-sample

By running **google-assistant-demo** I get this:

*pastebin.com/1dhaZqWY*
(I had quite a bit of issues trying to paste the link without code and when I post the code by itself it shows a bunch of other issues :) )

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Please show your code and state the error. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).*

Answer (score 0):

Wow that a lot of errors! Did you do the

`google-oauthlib-tool --client-secrets /home/pi/client_secret_client-id.json --scope https://www.googleapis.com/auth/assistant-sdk-prototype --save --headless`

bit properly?? remember you have to change the `client-id` bit to the random sequence of numbers and letters on the json file you downloaded earlier.